# Disable inputField conditionally

Tags: visualforce, inputfield, apexinputfile

As the apex:inputField doesn't support disabled attribute (but apex:inputText does), I was using arbitrary attribute html-disabled to accomplish this. But, I was wondering if we can add a condition or boolean to arbitrary attributes. I tried something like

```
<apex:inputField value="{!ObjA.inputPicklist1__c}" html-disabled="{!editFlag}"/>
```

and the field always remained disabled regardless of the flag value. So, conditional disabling of apex:inputField is not possible this way and can only be achieved via javascript?
Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

Better to show and hide the `apex:inputField` based on `rendered` attribute.

So, when `editFlag = true`, you will display:

```
<apex:inputField value="{!ObjA.inputPicklist1__c}" html-disabled="true" rendered="{!editFlag}"/>
```

when `editFlag = false`, you will display:

```
<apex:inputField value="{!ObjA.inputPicklist1__c}" rendered="{!!editFlag}"/>
```

Comment: Thank you. I have used rendering at different places, but it is not an option for me in this case as the page size is fixed, hiding many fields might leave off too much empty space and also we want the viewers to be aware that these fields are part of the page.

Answer (score 3):

if you don't want to use js, then you need to use two VF tags.

Assuming, you want the user to enter value and setting `editFlag`set to `true`.

And when you don't want the user to enter value, setting `editFlag`set to `false`.

You can try the below logic

```
<apex:inputField value="{!ObjA.inputPicklist1__c}" rendered="{!editFlag}"/>
<apex:outputField value="{!ObjA.inputPicklist1__c}" rendered="{!!editFlag}"/>
```

Comment: Thank you. I have used rendering at different places, but it is not an option for me in this case as the page size is fixed, hiding many fields might leave off too much empty space and also we want the viewers to be aware that these fields are part of the page.

Comment: Hi Seesh, You could also diable all input fields by using HTML FIELDSET(not Salesforce fieldset)..
Example
<form>
    <fieldset disabled>
    <legend>Personalia:</legend>
Name: <input type="text"><br>
    Email: <input type="text"><br>
    Date of birth: <input type="text">
  </fieldset>
</form>